# Using os.Stdin to input text, after end type text, why does the program can continue run?

Tags: go, client-server

I run a echo server at backend, also I run the client, at the client side, I need to input text in terminal and send to echo server, use golang os.Stdin to input text,but when i ended the type in terminal,the client program dosenot use for or while loop to input text ,why client program can continue run?

the client program with Go:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    go mustCopy(os.Stdout, conn)
    mustCopy(conn, os.Stdin)
}

//!-

func mustCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
    if _, err := io.Copy(dst, src);
    err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

the server side golang code is :

```
func echo(c net.Conn, shout string, delay time.Duration) {
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToUpper(shout))
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", shout)
    time.Sleep(delay)
    fmt.Fprintln(c, "\t", strings.ToLower(shout))
}


func handleConn(c net.Conn) {
    input := bufio.NewScanner(c)
    for input.Scan() {
        go echo(c, input.Text(), 1*time.Second)
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    c.Close()
}

//!-

func main() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err) // e.g., connection aborted
            continue
        }
        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

what confuse me is that the client side program why not stop run! As i understand ,it should stop run.thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the client has 2 goroutines in `io.Copy` -- that is all it's doing.

Comment: @JimB after run  client program ,i input the string text, after the server receive and send same text  to client ,the clinet read it .the client program can continue run,i can continue to  input text at the client side,and resend to server side.i dont know why i can continue to send text,the client dont use loop for continue to input text.

Comment: `io.Copy` must use a loop somewhere, that's how it can copy from a reader to a writer. Your client code has at least 2 "for loops", you just didn't write them directly. Just like if you called `http.ListenAndServe`, the loop is happening in other code.

Comment: @JimB thanks a lot ! i has understood

Comment: I had to recreate your imports to run your code.  Next time, please include your package declaration and imports unless you really don't have them.  Also include intended output and actual output from the terminal.

Comment: @DanielFarrell thanks your suggestion! next time i will care it .

Comment: Otherwise, nice job with including the full code - it works and reproduces the behavior you describe!  Very important and adds lots of value